# Optimal Google Cloud Storage for BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Given a 1-terabyte data set which comes from the sources in a couple hundred csv files, and divides naturally into two large tables, what's the best way to store the data in Google Cloud Storage?  Partitioning by date does not apply as the data is relatively static and only updated quarterly.  Is it best to combine all of the data into two large files and map each to a BigQuery table?  Is it better to partition?  If so, on what basis?  Is there a threshold file size above which BigQuery performance degrades?

Comment: This is a really broad question, and it's unclear exactly what you're asking TBH. Do you need to query this data or just store it? If former, than load it into BigQuery from GCS. If the latter, just leave it in GCS.

Comment: I want to query and have created a table in BiqQuery, but with only a subset of the data totaling a few GB. My question is if I have a TB of data should I keep it in one giant file GCS or should I split it up?

Comment: Just load it all into BigQuery. BigQuery eats TB's for breakfast.

Comment: Hi @GrahamPolley could you post your comment as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case:

- To query data => then load it into BigQuery from GCS.
- To store the data => leave it in GCS.

**Question:** *"I want to query and have created a table in BiqQuery, but with only a subset of the data totaling a few GB. My question is if I have a TB of data should I keep it in one giant file GCS or should I split it up?"*

**Answer:**  *Just load it all into BigQuery. BigQuery eats TB's for breakfast.*